# Opinion on where to place a function in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, directory, code-reuse

I've got a `command` (placed in Command/filename) which can be called from the command line. The function essentially clones an entity and modifies some of its features in a generic manner such as creation date etc.

To make this code reusable, I would need to move this function outside of the `command` but Im conflicted as to where to place it. I want it to logically make the most sense to be able to easily find this function.

I could create a helper directory and start placing code there, or maybe a repository directory within the entity directory, or maybe just place the code on the entity itself?

I was just wondering how some of the Symfony veterans out there would arrange their code.

```
foreach ($postcodeGeoLocations as $postcode => $geoLocation) {
        $location = new Location();
        $location->setLatitude($geoLocation['latitude']);
        $location->setLongitude($geoLocation['longitude']);

        $newAddress = clone $address;
        $newAddress->setLocation($location);
}
```

Comment: Sounds good, but I'm wondering where to place the service. We've got several File services already defined, but as this service is mid-way between a model and a helper Im trying to gather opinions on where to put the code within the file structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually setup a web project with different bundles: AdminBundle, FrontendBundle, CoreBundle. At this point is trivial to understand where a service is going to end up.

In terms of folder structure, I usually put services in a Service folder at the same level of Controller.

Caveat: they are usually small, focused services with single responsibility in mind. Code "mid-way between a model and a helper" maybe still needs a bit of polishing before turning into a service.